# Jetpack Compose: Bottom bar and Nested Navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have setup a Bottom Bar in project on Jetpack Compose app with 2 destinations. I have tried to follow the samples from Google.

So for example it looks something like this:

```
@Composable
fun ExampleBottomBar(navController: NavHostController) {
val items = listOf(
    BottomNavigationGraph.Graph1,
    BottomNavigationGraph.Graph2
)
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

BottomNavigation {
    items.forEach { screen ->
        BottomNavigationItem(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                        saveState = true
                    }

                    launchSingleTop = true
                    restoreState = true

                }
            },
            selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
            icon = { Icon(imageVector = screen.icon, contentDescription = null) },
            label = { Text(stringResource(screen.label)) }
        )
      }
     }
    }
```

This all works fine and I'm able to navigate between the two destinations. However, When I navigate from `Graph-1 Screen-2` to `Graph-2 Screen-2`, It navigates without any issue. But when I press Bottom Tab on `Graph-1`, it doesn't work. The Bottom Tab seems to be not clickable anymore.
So I tried this solution to navigate to nested screen (different graph):

```
navigate(route) {
    launchSingleTop = true
    restoreState = false
    popUpTo(graph.findStartDestination().id) {
        saveState = true
    }
}
```

Now this solution works perfectly. Now when I click on Bottom Tab for `Graph-1` it switches and retain state for `Graph-1 Screen-2`, But when I press back button from `Graph-2 Screen-2`, it navigates me directly to `Graph-1 Screen-1` which creates basically another stack for `Graph-1 Screen-1`.
So basically what I want is to retain state for `Graph-1 Screen-2` on back press or BottomTab click.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?
Can someone help me out here ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @AlvinDizon I didn't maintained the previous entries for bottom tab (when user press the back button from any tab). so here is hack - When pressing back button from any tab, you need to manually perform the top level navigation. By doing so, it will retain state for last nested screen for first tab.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting `saveState` and `restoreState` from `NavOptionsBuilder` as `false` helped to resolve the issue.